Complete Lattices and the Injectivity of the Restriction $f|_S$ - Verification of Proof
Attempt (General Case)
Conjecture: I want to show that if $X$ and $Y$ are nonempty sets, $(X, \leq)$ is a complete lattice, and $f: X \to Y$ is any well-defined function, then there exists a nonempty set $S \subseteq X$ such that the restriction function $f|_S$ is injective.
My Proof
Let $X$ and $Y$ be nonempty sets and $(X, \leq)$ be a complete lattice. Let $f: X \to Y$ be any well-defined function.
Define the equivalence relation $\sim $ on $X$ as
$$ x \sim y \iff f(x) = f(y)$$
The equivalence relation above is called the equivalence kernel of $f$. For all $x \in X$ define the equivalence class of $x$ as $[x] := \{y \in X : y \sim x\}$. Define $$m_x := \bigwedge [x]=\min([x])$$
$\\$
Claim #1: $m_{x}$ is well-defined for all $x \in X$.
Proof: Suppose $x,y \in X$  such that $x = y$. Then, since $f$ is well defined, $f(x) = f(y)$. This implies that $x \sim y$, and so $[x] = [y]$. The minimum function ($\min()$) is also well-defined. So, $m_x = \min([x]) = \min([y]) = m_y$. $\square$
$\\$
Claim #2: Let $x, y \in X$. Then $$x \sim y \iff m_x = m_y$$
Proof: Let $x, y \in X$.
($\Rightarrow$)
Suppose $x \sim y$. So, $[x] =[y]$. So $m_x = \inf([x]) = \inf([y]) = m_y$.
($\Leftarrow$) By Contraposition
Suppose $x \nsim y$. Then $x \notin [y]$. Hence, $[x] \cap [y] = \varnothing$. Therefore, for all $x\in X$ we have that $m_x \notin [y]$ and so $m_x \neq m_y$. $\square$
$\\$
Now, set $S := \{m_x : x \in X\}$.
Claim #3: $S \neq \varnothing$ and $S \subseteq X$.
Proof: Since $(X, \leq)$ is a nonempty complete lattice, $[x]$ always has an infimum. Therefore, $S \neq \varnothing$.
Take any $s \in S$. Then, there exists an $x \in X$ such that $s = m_x$. All complete lattices are bounded (have a minimum and maximum), and by definition, $m_x = \min([x]) \in X$. Therefore $s \in X$. $\square$
$\\$
Claim #4: If $s \in S$, then we have $m_s = s$.
Proof: Let $s \in S$. Then there exists an $x \in X$ such that $m_x = s$. T Equivalently, $s = \min([x]) \in [x]$. Also, since $S \subseteq X$, then $s \in X$. Therefore, $s \sim x$, or equivalently, $[s] = [x]$. Hence, $m_s = \min([s]) = \min([x]) = m_x = s$. $\square$
$\\$
Claim #5: $f|_S$ is injective and well-defined.
Proof:
Well-defined: Let $s_1, s_2 \in S$ such that $s_1 = s_2$. Then, $s_1 \sim s_2$, and so $f(s_1) = f(s_2)$. Finally, we have $f|_S (s_1) = f|_S (s_2)$.
Injective: Let $s_1, s_2 \in S$ such that $f|_S (s_1) = f|_S (s_2)$. Notice that by Claim #3, we have $s_1, s_2 \in X$. This implies that $f(s_1) = f(s_2)$. Therefore, $s_1 \sim s_2$ which (by Claim #2) we have that $m_{s_1} = m_{s_2}$. Finally, by Claim #4, we have $s_1 = s_2$. $\square$.

Isn't this trivial?  Just choose $S$ to be any one-element subset of $X$.

Hmmm never thought of that hahaha. Thanks. LMAO

If $f$ is just a function between sets, it doesn't care about the extra lattice structure on $X$.

Perhaps you were thinking about the situation in which we still have $f(S)=f(X)$? If so, you could do it without a lattice or any other algebraic structure, by just picking an element of each equivalence class to be a member of $S$ (but here, in the infinite case, you would need the Axiom of Choice).
